# Selecting all the keys which have a Maximum and Minimum values in Python Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am a newbie to a python dictionary. Excume me for my mistakes.

I want to create a list of **all** the keys which have a Maximum and Minimum values from Python Dictionary. I searched it about on Google but didn't get any answer.

I have written the following code:

```
a = {1:1, 2:3, 4:3, 3:2, 5:1, 6:3}
maxi = [keys for keys, values in a.items() if keys == max(a, key=a.get)]
mini = [keys for keys, values in a.items() if keys == min(a, key=a.get)]
print(maxi)
print(mini)
```

My output:

```
[2]
[1]
```

Expected output:

```
[2,4,6]
[1,5]
```

What did I do wrong? Is there any better (or other) way to do this?

I would be more than happy for your help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
a = {1:1, 2:3, 4:3, 3:2, 5:1, 6:3}

min_a = min(a.values())
max_a = max(a.values())

[k for k,v in a.items() if v == min_a]
# [1, 5]
[k for k,v in a.items() if v == max_a]
# [2, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

`a.values()` enumerates all the values of a dictionary `a` and so:

```
max_value = max(a.values())
min_value = min(a.values())
```

`a.items()` enumerates key, value tuples for each key, value pair in dictionary `a`. Putting this altogether:

```
a = {1:1, 2:3, 4:3, 3:2, 5:1, 6:3}
max_value = max(a.values())
min_value = min(a.values())

max_keys = [k for k, v in a.items() if v == max_value]
min_keys = [k for k, v in a.items() if v == min_value]

print(max_keys)
print(min_keys)
```

Prints:

```
[2, 4, 6]
[1, 5]
```